# "Http" directive not allowed - Failure to deploy java app to Amazon bean stalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have spring boot application which I am deploying on Amazon elastic bean stalk.
In my .ebextensions folder I have a file : 01_upload.config with below contents:

```
container_commands:
01_reload_nginx:
  test: pgrep nginx >/dev/null 2>&1
  command: "service nginx reload"
 files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
    http {
     client_max_body_size 400M;
    }
```

But the deployment to AWS fails with:

```
"http" directive is not allowed in    /etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf
```

However AWS document

> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

clearly says that "http" is a valid context .

Am I missing something in my Nginx  configuration ?